# Moving some matrix b(kxk) over the matrix a(nxm) with given stride, multiplying the corresponding elements, and adding them into the new matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

So here i have this problem.

> Given 2D numpy arrays 'a' and 'b' of sizes  m×n  and  k×k
> respectively (k <= n, k <= m), 2 integers 'stride' and 'padding' and
> 'f' function. You need to
>
> 1. first pad 'a' matrix with 0s on each side,
> 2. then move 'b' over 'a' with stride 'stride', then multiply their elements by the corresponding 'b' elements,
> 3. add the resulting k * k numbers
> 4. apply the 'f' function to the result
> 5. and place them in the new matrix.

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 2],
              [0, 1, 3],
              [1, 3, 0],
              [4, 5, 2]])
b = np.array([[1, 0],
              [0, 1]])
 
stride = 1
padding = 0
f = lambda x: x**2
print(conv(a, b, stride, padding, f))
>>[[4, 16],
  [9, 1],
  [36, 25]]
```

I don't understand how I should handle it in case if the stride is too large, for example if I set stride=2 in the example above, what will the program do? Will it take at first the [[1,1], [0,1]] then skip to the [[0,1], [1,3]], or somehow differently?
And what functions or method will be useful in this example, I already know how to pad matrices with 0s, but is there something else that could be useful?

Comment: Usually you do not take into account the value that does not fit. So if we take your example and we apply `conv(a,b,stride=2,padding=0,f)`, it will return `[[4],[36]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def padding(a, padd):
    matrix = np.zeros((len(a)+2*padd,len(a[0])+2*padd))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            matrix[i+padd,j+padd] = a[i,j]
    return matrix

def conv(a, b, stride, padd, f):
    output = np.zeros((len(a)-(len(b)-1),len(b)))
    c = padding(a,padd) 
    matrices = []
    for i in range(len(output)):
        column = stride - 1
        for j in range(len(output[0])):
            output[i,j] = np.sum(a[i:i+len(b),j+column:j+column+len(b)] * b)
    return f(output)

a = np.array([[1, 1, 2],
          [0, 1, 3],
          [1, 3, 0],
          [4, 5, 2]])
b = np.array([[1, 0],
          [0, 1]])
stride = 1
pad = 0
f = lambda x: x**2
print(conv(a, b, stride, pad, f))
```

Hello from 1991 )